# Check for instances of an object that might exist

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

Some preamble:
I have a windows service that has a timer firing every ten seconds (although configurable in the app.config). When the timer fires an event, the event handler creates an instance of an object (let's call it the Executor) that does some work. The Executor object creates background threads to execute a queue of tasks obtained from a DB.
Most of the time, the Executor's threads would have finished within about 60 seconds, so there is reasonable chance that at any one time, there are six or more instances of the Executor object, all doing some work (it's lightweight work, but can be long running as it gets and fetches and waits on stuff - after a period of time, it gives up if still not complete).

If the service is asked to stop, I don't want to leave these background threads behind, and under some circumstances, I might want to let the Executor objects finish before shutting down.

Is it possible, in the OnStop() method, to get a collection of instances of the Executor object, and check a property on each one, then make a decision from there?

My current thinking is that each time I instantiate Executor, I add it to a collection (and remove each instance when it's done), then consult that collection when I'm stopping. It seems clean-ish, but I'm wondering if there is a more 'fluid' way?

I understand I could also not bother, and just go with `RequestAdditionalTime` to cover what I think the maximum time could be to let it all finish up, but I wouldn't like to assume that there won't ever be slowness issues or bigger tasks in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection is the way to go. Add them and on end of the service go through each and have them kill their respective tasks.